# Authenticating a mobile app against a WCF service?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, authentication, soap

We are working with a vendor to develop a mobile app and plan on using WCF services to handle operations. What are some types of authentication I can use with a WCF service? Would we send a user name and password through the SOAP header? How can we accomplish this securely?

Also, this will be authenticated against our .NET membership database using the Membership classes. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to authenticate the user or the device ?

If it's the device, you could look into certificate-based authentication which isn't too easy to deploy in non-controlled environment but very secure and easy for the end user.

Otherwise, you will need to get some authentication data from the user himself (like a password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What O/S is the mobile device running?  It seems to me that the mobile device can use Windows Authentication if the mobile app is written using a framework (such as the .NET compact framework) to authenticate, just like you would with a web application.  Set up the connection to use SSL and you're golden.

Another means could be to write a challenge/response system similar to Windows Authentication - but this seems like overkill unless the mobile app is on an operating system that doesn't support Windows Auth.

If you're at all familiar with the ASP.NET MembershipProvider/RoleProvider/MembershipUser model, it's fairly easy to use once you get past the limitations their model incurs.

Comment: The mobile device can be an iphone or droid. 

Our tech lead discovered a built in WCF service that will handle SOAP authentication (System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService) which we were going to look into further. I don't know much about this at the moment but wanted to see how, in general, generic clients would authenticate against a WCF service and the built in Membership model.